# How to make an Input element on a form carry a specific entry?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web-deployment

I am creating two different web pages, on the first page are a list of products for sale, on the second page is a form any buyer would fill to complete their purchase.

So, there is an input entry on the form that must carry the name of the product clicked on from the previous page. **What JavaScript do I need to do this?**

I created a function; `var x == document.getElementByName("h3")`, `h3` carries the name of the product in the first page.

Comment: One option would be to include the product id in the address of the 2nd page. Then assign that GET variable to whatever form field.